# Is it possible to sort a .NET DataGridView column using only the keyboard?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

Is it possible, out of the box, to sort a .NET DataGridView column using only the keyboard?

I understand there is a SelectionMode property, but changing this merely allows me to select, using Shift+Space, an entire row or column, but this doesn't have the same effect as clicking the header with the mouse and causing a sort.

The reason I ask is because I am working on accessibility issues and would like to avoid relying on the mouse.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: by "out of the box" do you mean "no code required"?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguity, I was hoping there's a way to do this without code that I didn't know about.

Comment: I don't think there is. The good news is that it shouldn't take very much code. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you will need to do is set the `KeyPreview` property to `True` in your form properties.

Then in the events you need to add an event handler for the `KeyDown()` event

Then add some code something like this:

```
public class Form1{
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //sort column 0 descending on a 'D' press
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);

        //sort column 0 Ascending on a 'U' press
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.U)
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I'm missing something, but call Sort method at the moment you receive desired Key combination.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know that the column headers ever get focus (ctrl+tab/etc?), but if they could and your keyboard has a context menu button, that *could* work. but i don't think the headers ever get keyboard focus.

Otherwise, there may be ways to do it using standard accessability features?